# Excel textbox resizes in different computer

Tags: excel

I have created a excel with many textboxes in it, in my laptop it looks fine but in some users laptop textbox size is reduced automatically, causing alignment issues. Below is the laptop configuration in both cases:

Os Win 11, screen resolution 1920 x 1080, Scale & Layout 150%, Excel version - Microsoft 365

Laptop 1 (Glitches):
[image: Excel with textbox Glitch]

Laptop 2 (normal view):
[image: Excel with textbox normal]

Location of Laptop 1 - US
Location of Laptop 2 - India

Will location play any role, in displaying excel content.

I have ensured windows display setting remains the same in 2 laptop.

I have tried changing excel->Advance Option -> Default resolution to 220 ppi, 330 ppi, etc. but it did not seems to work.

Any solution will be really helpful, so that textbox remains same in all laptops.